# Basic Java questions Scanning

Tags: java, debugging

This is very basic java that i'm struggling with n00b style.  it just prints out this

Please enter '.' when you want to calculate
1 2 3
.
Numbers are 1 2 3
The Sum is0The Product is1

when it is supposed to calculate the sum and product of those consecutive numbers. something is wrong id appreciate any help!

main method

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class NumberScanned {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("Please enter '.' when you want to calculate");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

                String scannedString = keyboard.nextLine();
                Scanning scanz= new Scanning(scannedString);



     while(!keyboard.nextLine().equals("."))
     {
         scanz.set(scannedString);
     }

        keyboard.close();

        System.out.println("Numbers are"+scannedString);   

    scanz.printState();
        }
    }

Class Scanning


public class Scanning {
     int num;
      int sum;
      int product;
      String userInput;
            public Scanning(String userInput)
            {
                 num=0;
                 sum=0;
                  product=1;
            this.userInput=userInput;
            }
      public void set(String userInput)
      {
      for(int index=0; index<userInput.length(); index++)
            {

                if(Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index))==true)
                {

                num=userInput.charAt(index);


                sum+=num;
                product*=num;




                }
                else
                {


                    index++;
                }



            } 

      }

      public void printState()
      {
         System.out.println("The Sum is"+sum+"The Product is"+product); 
      }

}
```

Comment: >something is wrong       Can you explain?  If there are errors, please copy full text and paste it here.

Comment: all the code is there!

Comment: You didn't explain what was wrong.

Comment: yes i did it says sum is 0 and product is 1 when its supposed to calculate the sum and product from those numbers

Comment: Ohh i read the question wrong, well you never even parse the numbers into integers
well you are checking if(Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index))==false)
so thats checking if its not a number, therefore if you type in letters it should run and work

Comment: oh wait I had it as true before and it still didn't work i'll change that. I want it to be looking for a digit

Comment: BTW System.out.println((int)'1'); prints 49 so you have to parse it or it will give you the (ASCII?, UNICODE? idk) reference for the character.

Comment: isnt this already parsing it though it wont ley me do any other sort of parsing if(Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index))==true)
                {
                num=userInput.charAt(index);

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look at:

- We know `keyboard.nextLine()` gets the input from the console, but where are you checking it's validity (more importantly, when do you check it?). Are you looking at all input or just the last line?
- `isDigit` will return true if the passed in character is a number. Do you want to operate on numbers or characters in your `for` loop?

  - (a side note, What happens if I enter "1 10" in the console?)
- A `for` loop will automatically increment its index at the end of a loop, so an additional `++` is unnecessary

Comment: numbers since i'm doing calculations. we don't have to do any error checking so it's whateva. we are just assuming its typed in correctly isn't that lovely?

Comment: So when you're performing the `Character.isDigit() == false` check will that tell you if a character is a number or character?

Comment: no i changed it to  if(Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index))==true) that was a typo i was experimenting. it tells you if its a number...at least thats what I thought it did. which is why I think parsing isn't necessary because ints accept chars that have been identified as digits

Comment: For the first point, I was more getting at how many lines of input do you get before you call `scanz.set()`? What happens if the input is "1 2 3 (new line) ." vs "(new line) 1 2 3 (new line) ."?

Comment: we assume it's just going to be   "1 2 3 4 5" (new line) "."   if you do "1 2 3" new line "1 2 3 4" new line "." it gives me 49 for both

Comment: So you've changed the code so it works now, or are there still outstanding questions you have on it?

Comment: Look at the use cases when `scanz.set()` gets called. If the first input line is "1 2 3" and the second line is ".", how many times will the `while` loop execute? (Hint: Add a System.out line inside the loop to see for yourself).

Comment: it should only once when i add a system out line it doesn't print anything in the loop so maybe it doesn't execute at all? I just don't know why it's not doing that

Comment: Right. A `while()` loop can execute 0 or more times, while a `do...while()` loop will execute 1 or more times. Look at what the code is doing: you read the first input line, then when you get to the `while` loop you're checking if the second line is equal to ".". If it is, then you bypass the code in the `while` loop.

Comment: Ohhh so that's the difference! Thanks. now the sum is just printing out as The Sum is150The Product is124950 hahaha it never ends

Comment: :) Did you move the `printState` inside a loop? If you post the updated code we can take a look, or you can attempt to debug it yourself now that you know where to look :)?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helful in case you just need the sum and product values of a user entered
values.

```
public class ProductSumCalculator{
private static List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    getInputs();
    calculateSumAndProduct();
}

private static void getInputs() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter numbers or ctrl+z to end inputs");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }       
}
private static void calculateSumAndProduct() {
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = numbers.iterator();
    int sum=0;
    int product=1;
    int nextVal;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        nextVal = iterator.next();
        sum+=nextVal;
        product*=nextVal;
    }
    System.out.println("Value entered are: "+numbers+".\nThe sum is "+
              sum+".The product    is "+product);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. You can calculate the sum and product of all the int from your string line input like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scanning {

    /*
     * This method returns the integer. If while
     * conversion an Exception is thrown it returns
     * null. Otherwise the integer.
     */
    public static Integer tryParse(String text) {
          try {
            return Integer.parseInt(text);
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
          }
        }

    /*
     * Next String line is scanned. It is split by space. 
     * Stores String tokens in an String array from one String variable.
     * Then passed to tryParse() class method. null or auto Boxed Integer
     * is returned accordingly. It is auto unboxed from Integer
     * object to int variable. Then sum and product is calculated and
     * the final result is printed on the console Or Integrated
     * Development Environment.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strInts = keyboard.nextLine();

        String[] splits = strInts.split("\\s+");




        int i = 0;
        Integer anInteger = null;

        int total = 0;
        int product = 1;
        while((i < splits.length)) {

                anInteger = tryParse(splits[i]);



        if(anInteger != null) {
            total = total + anInteger;
            product = product * anInteger;
        }
        ++i;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + total);
        System.out.println("The product is: " + product);

    }

}
```